# Storing access tokens in the user's collection is better or separate?

Tags: python, mongodb, access-token

I am using `mongodb` with `python` and trying to figure out how should I store the access tokens, whether I should go with embedded documents and store access tokens in the same user's collection or create a new `collection` called `access_tokens` and keep a reference field of user in that?

Here's the example with different collection:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8bc5efac5a49b53fddb4d6"),
    "name" : "Rohit Khatri",
    "email" : "rohit@email.com",
    "username" : "rohit",
    "password" : "password"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8bdc2aac5a49b82c1f4e32"),
    "token" : "sf33849hskjdfhj9348khsjdf",
    "expires_at" : ISODate("2018-09-02T12:48:42.218Z"),
    "user_id" : {
        "$ref" : "users",
        "$id" : ObjectId("5b8bc5efac5a49b53fddb4d6")
    }
}
```

With embedded collection

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8bc5efac5a49b53fddb4d6"),
    "name" : "Rohit Khatri",
    "email" : "rohit@email.com",
    "username" : "rohit",
    "password" : "password",
    "access_tokens": [
        {
            "token" : "sf33849hskjdfhj9348khsjdf",
            "expires_at" : ISODate("2018-09-02T12:48:42.218Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Which way is better in terms of performance, scalability, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One nice side effect of keeping the tokens in a separate collection is that you could use a [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) on that collection to automatically delete older token records. The index isn’t guaranteed to run exactly at the time you have set in your expires_at field but it would be very close to that time if accuracy in seconds isn’t important to you. That way all you’d need to check is if the token exists and not whether it’s expired.

Comment: It's not a concern that whether the token persist after the expiry time, because every time the api is called, I will fetch and check If the token is valid and if not, will delete the token and give error to user.

Comment: @RohitKhatri I would still recommend keeping the tokens in a separate collection, since you may want more than one token per user at some point in the future. Imagine for instance you want to provide an integration of your app with Facebook at some point in the future. Then maybe you want to provide an Instagram integration. Now imagine then user wants to disable the Facebook integration but keep the Instagram one. In that situation, you’d want to revoke the one token and keep the other. Keeping tokens in the user object would get unnecessarily complex in a situation like that.

Comment: I know, but that action is not too frequent and won't be that complex to do, and we can also manage multiple access tokens with embedded document as well.